# PL/SQL Procedure with SELECT return value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

New to PL/SQL and I've tried to mess around with this and figure it out, but at a loss. Hoping for you guy's expertise and guidance.

Here's the code I have, hopefully you can kind of see where I am trying to get to. I know I need a cursor or a loop, maybe to get this to work properly. However, I am not sure where placement goes and how to get this to work.

Any help is appreciated.

```
create or replace
procedure customer_credit(cust_ID IN NUMBER) AS
    credit_num NUMBER;
    begin
       select CUSTOMER_ID, CREDIT_LIMIT from OE.CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=cust_ID;
       dbms_output.put_line('Credit Limit = ', || credit_num);
end;
/
exec customer_credit(145);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Not clear.  you want to return a value? You do not need a loop to return a single value.  You don't even need a stored procedure, unless you are just trying that out for learning purposes.

Comment: Learning....need to input a Customer ID and return the Credit_Limit form the Customers Table

Comment: You don't need cursor or a loop unless there are multiple rows from the select. I assume customer_id is the primary key and there should be a single row returned. Moreover, If your intention is to have  *"input a Customer ID and return the Credit_Limit from the Customers Table"* ,(  and you are learning PLSQL) writing a function should be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of options.  One is to use a SELECT... INTO:

```
create or replace
procedure customer_credit(cust_ID IN NUMBER) AS
    credit_num NUMBER;
    begin
       select CREDIT_LIMIT 
       into credit_num
       from OE.CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=cust_ID;
       dbms_output.put_line('Credit Limit = ', || credit_num);
end;
```

It the row is not found, this will generate an exception.  You can fix that either by adding an exception handler, or use an explicit open/fetch/close cursor method. If you are executing the procedure from sqlplus, you need to first call

```
set serveroutput on
```

to see the results of dbms_output.

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense....I need the INTO to push the data result into a variable.

Comment: @Sam - yes, you need the `INTO` clause. You also only need to `SELECT` the `CREDIT_LIMIT` column, not the `CUSTOMER_ID` column, as you were doing in your attempt. That column is indeed needed in the `WHERE` clause, but not in `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value to be returned, it is better to define this as a FUNCTION and then invoke the function in your code. This will allow you to use it in both PL/SQL procedures and SELECT statements. You should also use exception handlers to handle situations. I have modified your example to illustrate the changes needed:

```
create or replace
function customer_credit(cust_ID IN NUMBER)
return number
IS
    credit_num NUMBER;
begin
       select CREDIT_LIMIT
       into   credit_num
       from OE.CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=cust_ID;
       dbms_output.put_line('Credit Limit = ', || credit_num);
       return(credit_num);
exception
  when NO_DATA_FOUND then
    return(0);
end;
/
select customer_credit(145) from dual;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Your Procedure is compiled with warnings, you've declared the variable credit_num, but are not passing any value into this variable.(So How Can This Variable will return Something if it doesn't have anything.)

If you want to get the CREDIT_LIMIT from Your Table Then You should Write Your code using Select Into for ex:-

```
select CREDIT_LIMIT 
into credit_num 
from OE.CUSTOMERS 
where CUSTOMER_ID=cust_id;
```

Just change your select statement and you're good to go with your Program.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `Cursor`, alternatively :

```
create or replace procedure customer_credit( cust_ID IN NUMBER) as
begin
  for c in ( select CUSTOMER_ID, CREDIT_LIMIT from CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=cust_ID )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Credit Limit = '|| c.CREDIT_LIMIT);
  end loop;
end;
```

By the way, there's a typo (`comma`) which should be removed inside `dbms_output.put_line()` clause. As @OldProgrammer stated, `set serveroutput on` should be issued to see the results .

Comment: Presumably, `ID` represents something "unique", so that `select` returns a single value (at most) anyway. So, what would be a purpose of looping through a single row? Not that it is *wrong*, but ... doesn't make much sense either. Of course, if my presumption is correct. Otherwise, you're correct :)

Comment: @Littlefoot exactly, nice approach :)

Answer (score 0):

this will work :

```
create or replace
procedure customer_credit(cust_ID IN NUMBER) AS
    credit_num NUMBER;
    begin
       select CREDIT_LIMIT into credit_num from OE.CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=cust_ID;
       dbms_output.put_line('Credit Limit = ', || credit_num);
end;
/
exec customer_credit(145);
```